# Regular Expression for Upto 4 Digits Even Integers

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

In an MVC project I need to validate number of pages of a book using Data Annotations method like following coding sample. Number of pages can be an even integer anything between 0 to 9998 inclusive.

```
[DisplayName("Pages (Including Cover):")]
[RegularExpression("reg_ex_string",ErrorMessage="Invalid Value")]
public int pages { get; set; }
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the regex work properly client side, or does it merely hit ModelState as being invalid? I have found a better approach is to use the range annotation.

Comment: @TravisJ: Regex works on client side. How could you use Range Annotation for validating even numbers within a given range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero to three digits followed by 0, 2, 4, 6 or 8:

```
^\d{0,3}[02468]$
```

Comment: Just to be safe, I anchored it to the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Is it possible to make it 0 exclusive. ie; 2-9998 even integer?

Comment: Sure, `^[2468]|(\d{1,3}[02468])$`